# List Item UI design with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am beginner for flutter.

I have one lock icon image, that need to display half within cell and half out of cell.

I want to create UI for ListItem.

[image]

I already write code as below, but it not work:

```
ListTile makeListTile() => ListTile(
  contentPadding:
  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),

  title: Text(
    "Item Title",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),

  subtitle: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        flex: 0,
            child: Icon(Icons.settings, size: 20.0),),
      Expanded(
          flex: 4,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
            child: Text("120",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54))),),
      Expanded(
        flex: 4,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
            child: Text("150",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54))),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.add, size:  20,)),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
            child: Text("1",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54))),),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.add, size:  20,)),
      )
    ],
  ),
  trailing:
      new Stack(
        children:[
      Icon(Icons.lock, size: 20.0)
      ]),
  onTap: () {

  },
);
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add code, which you have tried your self first.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try first yourself, because it will help to learn a different way to build the UI. If it's urgent then here is the code. But again **I suggest trying yourself first**. Everything in the dummy you need to change according to your requirement.

```
Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.yellow)),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Item Name',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 14.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.close,
                                  color: Colors.yellow,
                                  size: 30.0,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.adjust,
                                      color: Colors.yellow,
                                      size: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Dummy Text',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 14.0),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.add_circle_outline,
                                      color: Colors.yellow,
                                      size: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                    Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                                    Text(
                                      '1',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 14.0),
                                    ),Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.remove_circle,
                                      color: Colors.yellow,
                                      size: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                    Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0))
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.group,
                        size: 30.0,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
```

This is how its look like for now:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1 use stack widget
2 add card with hight wight
3 add right side icon
4 add column
5 add row inside column